# Using selenium webdriver via powershell

Tags: powershell, selenium-webdriver

We have been trying  to login gmail via selenium web driver like below. But no luck.

Here is my error message:

```
Exception calling "FindElementByXPath" with "1" argument(s): "no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()='Next']"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.190)"
```

script :

```
# Website and credential variables
$YourURL = "http://www.gmail.com" # Website we'll access

# Invoke Selenium into our script!
$env:PATH += ";C:\Temp\PSL\" # Adds the path for ChromeDriver.exe to the environmental variable 
Add-Type -Path "C:\Temp\PSL\WebDriver.dll" # Adding Selenium's .NET assembly (dll) to access it's classes in this PowerShell session
$ChromeDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver # Creates an instance of this class to control Selenium and stores it in an easy to handle variable

# Make use of Selenium's class methods to manage our browser at will
$ChromeDriver.Navigate().GoToURL($YourURL) # Browse to the specified website
$ChromeDriver.FindElementByName("identifier").SendKeys("my_gmailuser@gmail.com") 
$ChromeDriver.FindElementByXPath("//span[text()='Next']").Click
$ChromeDriver.FindElementByName("password").SendKeys("MY_password")

$ChromeDriver.FindElementByXPath("//span[text()='Next']").Click

# Cleaning up after ourselves!
Pause
Function Stop-ChromeDriver {Get-Process -Name chromedriver -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
$ChromeDriver.Close() 
$ChromeDriver.Quit() 
Stop-ChromeDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add a wait condition before this line

```
$ChromeDriver.FindElementByXPath("//span[text()='Next']").Click
```

I would go with the Expected condition "element to be clickable". It will wait for the element to be loaded in DOM, and then to be visible and clickable. More info [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/).

Comment: thanks at this time I'm not getting error. But no action Next button.  There is cmd output like below. no any error message.  `OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
void Click()
void IWebElement.Click()`